# MongoDB replica set initiate() failing on Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to set up a MongoDB replica set on Docker follwoing this [guide](http://shellfu.com/setting-up-a-mongodb-replica-set-on-docker/). However when I get to the `rs.intitate()` command, I get an error.

```
"errmsg" : "replSetInitiate quorum check failed because not all proposed set members responded affirmatively: mongo-local-002:27017 failed with Connection refused, mongo-local-003:27017 failed with Connection refused"
```

edit: using latest version of docker container (3.6)

edit2: the problem is actually with mongo 3.6 (3.4 works). I have tried binding each replica ip to an ip in the docker network, however in this way I am not able to open the mongo console on the main replica (it says connection refused) even passing the IP instead of the replica name.

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Comment: What version of MongoDB server are you using? The guide you are following is using MongoDB 3.2.8, so there may be changes for newer versions of MongoDB. In particular, MongoDB 3.6 and newer will [bind to localhost by default](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#bind-ip-compatibility) so you will need to pass a [`--bind_ip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) parameter to your `mongod` instances or set `net.bindIp` in their configuration files if you want to allow remote connections for replication.

Comment: @Stennie Thank you, that may very well be the problem. Should I then just bind the replicas to ip addresses in the mongo-rs-local docker network ?

Comment: You should be able to bind to an IP in your Docker network but it looks like you've tried that and are still having issues. Can you add the output of `rs.conf()` and the `mongod` command line you are using? If this is a local development deployment you might want to try with `--bind_ip=0.0.0.0` for similar behaviour to MongoDB 3.4 with no `bind_ip` (i.e. bind to all IPs if none is provided via command line or configuration file). The `mongod` processes will need to be able to connect to each other on the host and port names specified in the configuration you pass to `rs.initiate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in MongoDB 3.6, MongoDB binaries, mongod and mongos, bind to localhost by default. You need to start every mongod with **--bind_ip**. Try to bind not only a specific ip but to all IPv4. To bind to all IPv4 addresses, you can specify the bind ip address of 0.0.0.0. That way you will verify if the bind to a specific ip is the problem.